# How the user can save the gui(result) in other folder?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, save

You all here realy help me with matlab since i am a beginner. Now i know a little bit about gui in matlab. I have a question. i have a figure of gui and a save button. I did this coding:

```
filename = inputdlg('Please enter the name for your figures');

extensions = {'fig','bmp'};

for k = 1:length(extensions

saveas(gcf, filename{:}, extensions{k})

set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')

end
```

But this only can save at the folder of my gui. How i want to make the user can choose which folder that he want to save the gui in .bmg file??

I use this coding as an edit from @gnovice suggestion:

```
filename = inputdlg('Please enter the name for your figures');

extensions = {'fig','bmp'};

directoryName = uigetdir;  %# Open directory-selection dialog

if directoryName == 0      %# User pressed the "Cancel" button...

  directoryName = '';      %#   ...so choose the empty string for the folder

end

saveas(gcf,fullfile(directoryName,fileName),extension);  %# Save to the folder

set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')
```

But this error occured:

```
??? Error while evaluating uipushtool ClickedCallback

??? Undefined function or variable 'fileName'.

Error in ==> fyp_editor>uipushtool9_ClickedCallback at 1605
saveas(gcf,fullfile(directoryName,fileName),extension);  %# Save to the folder

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in ==> fyp_editor at 42
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in ==>
@(hObject,eventdata)fyp_editor('uipushtool9_ClickedCallback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


??? Error while evaluating uipushtool ClickedCallback
```

Comment: The error occurs because in my example below I use the name `fileName` in camel case, whereas you use `filename` in all lowercase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You apparently already know about the [INPUTDLG](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/inputdlg.html) dialog box (since you use it above), so I'm surprised you haven't also come across the [UIGETDIR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uigetdir.html) dialog box (or [any of the others](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/f16-40727.html#f16-8026) for that matter). You can use this to let the user browse and choose a folder, like so:

```
fileName = inputdlg('Please enter the name for your figures');
directoryName = uigetdir('','Please select a folder to save to');
if directoryName == 0      %# User pressed the "Cancel" button...
  directoryName = '';      %#   ...so choose the empty string for the folder
end
filePath = fullfile(directoryName,fileName{1});  %# Create the file path
extensions = {'fig','bmp'};
for k = 1:length(extensions)
  saveas(gcf,filePath,extensions{k});  %# Save the file
  set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto');
end
```

Note that I used the function [FULLFILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fullfile.html) to construct the file path, which automatically takes care of the [file separators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/filesep.html) needed for your given platform.

Comment: i believe that the directoryname==0 is not function because it appears an error above there.